# Is there some Junit testcases for List and Set and Map in java?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, junit, testcase

Recently I'm doing some work about creating some kinds of data structures.

So I need some test cases to make sure they runs right.

So as there are already so many data structures implemented, I wonder if there already be some free testcases for common use?

Creating tests are sooooooo boring after all.

The one I'm using now is like:

```
package com.xenoamess.commons.primitive.collections.lists.array_lists;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

/**
 * @author XenoAmess
 */
public class LongArrayListTest {

    public void checkEqual(LongArrayList a1, ArrayList<Long> a2) {
        assertEquals(a1.size(), a2.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            assertEquals(a1.get(i), a2.get(i));
            assertEquals(a1.getPrimitive(i), (long) a2.get(i));
        }
        assertEquals(a1, a2);
        assertEquals(a2, a1);
    }

    public void check(int length) {
        LongArrayList a1 = new LongArrayList();
        ArrayList<Long> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            long l = random.nextLong();
            a1.add(l);
            a2.add(l);
        }

        checkEqual(a1, a2);

        boolean flag = false;
        for (Long l : a2) {
            flag = !flag;
            if (flag) {
                a1.remove(l);
            } else {
                a1.removeByContentPrimitive(l);
            }
        }

        assertTrue(a1.isEmpty());

        a1.addAll(a2);

        checkEqual(a1, a2);

        a1.sort(null);
        a2.sort(null);

        checkEqual(a1, a2);
    }

    public void performanceChecks(int length) {
        Random random = new Random();
        LongArrayList data = new LongArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            long l = random.nextLong();
            data.addPrimitive(l);
        }

        long begin1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LongArrayList a1 = new LongArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            a1.addPrimitive(data.getPrimitive(i));
        }
        a1.sort(null);
        Object a1c = a1.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            a1.removeByContentPrimitive(data.getPrimitive(i));
        }
        long score1 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin1);
        System.out.println("LongArrayList time : " + score1);

        long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<Long> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            a2.add(data.getPrimitive(i));
        }
        a2.sort(null);
        Object a2c = a2.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            a2.remove((Object) data.getPrimitive(i));
        }
        long score2 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin2);
        System.out.println("ArrayList<Long> time : " + score2);
        assertTrue(score2 > score1);
        assertEquals(a1c, a2c);
    }

    @Test
    public void checks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            check(100);
        }
        System.out.println("micro end");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            check(10000);
        }
        System.out.println("small end");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            check(100000);
        }
        System.out.println("medium end");
//        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
//            check(1000000);
//        }
        System.out.println("large deleted");
        System.out.println("performance checks started:");
        performanceChecks(100000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may reference the test case from [open jdk](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/test/java/util/)

Comment: Not really the answer you are looking for, but using an assertion library like `AssertJ` (or `Hamcrest`) will make you test quicker and easier as they have lots of methods for asserting the contents of collections, which you may even be able to extend for your collection type

Comment: If your source code is fairly small and self-contained take a look at [Diffblue Playground](https://playground.diffblue.com/home). It will automatically generate tests for you.